# R function is returning "Character (0)" instead of Cardinal Direction

Tags: r, function

I am attempting to convert wind direction (values 0-360) into a cardinal direction (ie NW). My code is below:

```
DegToDer <- function(degree) {
  value <- as.integer((degree / 45)+ .5)
  direction <- c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW")
  return(direction[((value+1) %% 8)])}
```

When I run it on my column I get the following error:

> replacement has 346 rows, data has 365

I've tested it out with a few values and found out that every thing that should return the value "NE" is only returning "character (0)"

```
> DegToDer(293)
character(0)
> DegToDer(292)
[1] "W"
> DegToDer(360)
[1] "N"
```

Any and all assistance on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add one after you do the mod (`%%`). Mod returns 0-7. `return(direction[((value+1) %% 8)+1])`

Comment: instead of before the `%%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `%%` formula is slightly wrong.

```r
degree <- 0:90

DegToDer <- function(degree) {
    value <- as.integer(degree / 45 + 0.5)
    direction <- c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW")
    return(direction[(value %% 8) + 1])
}

table(DegToDer(degree))
#> 
#>  E  N NE 
#> 23 23 45
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant! Now that you've pointed it out its so obvious! <3 Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem here is that R indexes vectors starting at 1, so if you provide a value like `floor((293/45)+0.5)+1` that returns 8, your index will be 0 and the function return value will be `NA`

How about you try to work with the base R function [`cut`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/cut)?

```
DegToDer <- function (degree) {
  return(cut(
    x = degree,
    breaks = c(0, seq(22.5, 337.5, 45), 360),
    labels = c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW","N"),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  ))
}
```

Comment: I was able to successfully use cut to get it to work without using the function code ... I like how this combines both of those elements!